# cannot find symbol java

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to allow a user to select between two options, and then use this in         `aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);`

I have a page where the user selects between a3 and a4, but I am unable to pass this variable, as if I try `aset.add(MediaSizeName.variable);` I get the error `cannot find symbol`, even though it is already declared `public String paperSize;` and is passed when the user submits a value, basically how can I use a variable to change the `.ISO` bit?

Thanks

EDIT

```html
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{printerSettings.paperSize}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="ISO_A5" itemLabel="A5" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="ISO_A4;" itemLabel="A4" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="ISO_A3" itemLabel="A3" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

above is where the user selects the size

now i pass the value :

```html
<p:commandButton type="submit"
    action="#{printInTen.countDown(printerSettings.t, printerSettings.p, printerSettings.paperSize)}"
    onclick="Thankyou()" value="Print" />
```

and am trying to pass the value `paperSize`

```
public String paperSize;
    public String orienation;

    public void countDown(int t, int p, String paperSize) {

 System.out.println("Now setting up attributes such as page size");
        System.out.println ("Copies " + p);
        aset.add(new Copies(p)); //having issues, will not work currently although code is fine// NOW WORKING :D
        aset.add(MediaSizeName.paperSize);// will not let me use the variable here, 
        aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
        aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
```

but no matter what I try, the variable value I pass does not work in the  `aset.add(MediaSizeName.paperSize);` I get the error `cannot find symbol`

Comment: How do you expect us to be able to answer this question? We can't read your code between the lines. Please read your own question, and imagine that you don't have any knowledge about your code.

Comment: Post the example of your code.

Comment: Yeah sorry its hard to explain, but i want to change the .iso_a4 bit using a variable but everything i try doesn't work, is it possible to use a variable here

Comment: added, sorry about the poor quality of the original question hopefully this is more helpful

Comment: Show us the `MediaSizeName` class

Comment: MediaSizeName is a constant it's not a string you can't do this `MediaSizeName.paperSize`

Comment: that class is a sub class of media : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaSizeName.html  i do not have the class in my code

Comment: thank you robonerd, is there anything i can do with it

Comment: To begin with, a JSF managed bean is not the same as an entity class, it's more similar to a controller class, so it would be better to *merge* your `printerSettings` and your `printInTen` beans.

Comment: Add a conditional statements that compare your `paperSize` with all the options that are available, and than create actual constant like: `aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (paperSize.equals("ISO_A3")) {
    aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A3);
} else if (paperSize.equals("ISO_A4")) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: @user2065929 you had a Java basic programming problem, not a JSF problem. Still, make your test and let us know if you don't have any other problem.